# Prove that $r^3 + r - 2 = 0$ has a rational root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm currently a math major, but as of now, proofs are relatively new to me: the only class I've done to completion involving proofs is Intro to Proofs, and I took the class half a year ago. So as practice, I wanted to solve a problem that involved both proofs AND college algebra because I love algebra. Here's a problem that is made up:

Prove that $r^3+r-2=0$ has a rational root.

Here's how I would do it. First, I include scratch work that includes synthetic division: $(r^3+r-2)/(r-1)$.

Scratch Work:

\begin{array}{c|rrr}&1&0&1&-2\\1&&1&1&2\\\hline\\&1&1&2&0\\\end{array}

This tells me that $r^3+r-2$ has a root $1$. Now I write my proof.

Proof. Let $r$ be a root of $r^3+r-2=0$. By way of synthetic division, $r^3+r-2=(r-1)(r^2+r+2)$. Then, $r-1=0$ and $r^2+r+2=0$. Moreover, $r=1 \in \mathbb Q$ . Therefore, $r^3+r-2=0$ has a rational root.

But I have two questions:

1. Is my proof good, or am I missing some statements, have errors in my proof, etc.?
2. Will I encounter questions like this in more advanced math courses, beyond Intro to Proofs? I didn't see a question like this in my Intro to Proof course and expected such.

Thanks, and have a good day!

Comment: Seems like a lot of work. If you think that $1$ might be a root, just evaluate at $1$.  You get $1+1-2=0$, so $1$ is indeed a root.

Comment: In general, the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) gives you a short list of candidates which is sure to include *all* rational roots of a given polynomial. Then it's just a simple matter of checking each one.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for this comment! I'm aware of this, but I still wanted to show my work to recall synthetic division. It was one of my favorite topics from college algebra.

Comment: See my comment to the answer of TonyK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a sledgehammer to crack a nut $-$ synthetic division is not needed here. To prove that $r^3+r-2$ has a rational root, it suffices to exhibit an explicit rational root, namely $r=1$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Good eye! I'm aware I can just say (1)^3 + 1 - 2 = 0 and be done with it. But, I wanted a good starting point on the website. Right now, I'm taking Analysis, but I don't have a full grasp on it yet. I just know basic proof knowledge and propositional logic.

Comment: I would express the issue even more strongly.  Given any polynomial $$f(x) = a^nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x^1 + a_0,$$  then synthetic division will verify that a specific linear factor $(x - x_0)$ is a factor of $f(x)$ **if and only if** $f(x_0) = 0.$  So, the shortcut to attempting synthetic division with a *candidate* linear factor $(x - x_0)$ is to **instead** check whether $f(x_0)$ happens to equal $(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor the left hand side of the equation. $0=r^3 +r - 2 = r^3 -1 + r -1 = (r-1)(r^2+r+1) + r-1 = (r-1)(r^2+r+1+1) = (r-1)(r^2+r+2)\implies r = 1$ is the only real and rational root. The other roots are irrational by Descartes's rule of sign or by direct computation using quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach from the other users:
\begin{align*}
r^{3} + r - 2 & = (r^{3} - r) + (2r - 2)\\\\
& = r(r^{2} - 1) + 2(r - 1)\\\\
& = r(r + 1)(r - 1) + 2(r - 1)\\\\
& = [r(r + 1) + 2](r - 1)\\\\
& = (r^{2} + r + 2)(r - 1)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!